# how to group by ef entity with two properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have for example entity with multiple properties 'myEntity' and I want to Group By 'Age' and 'sex

```
public class myEntity
{
public int Id{get; set;}
public string FirstName{get; set;}
public string LastName{get; set;}
public int sex{get; set;}
public int Age{get; set;}
}
```

I try the following query but I get error

```
var resultTable= dbContext.CashVacs.GroupBy(g => g.sex, g => g.age);
```

Comment: So what error do you get?

Comment: Maybe `var resultTable= dbContext.CashVacs.GroupBy(g => new {g.sex, g.Age});`?

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @MikeMozhaev's comment, the `GroupBy` method only takes one property which it uses for grouping.

In your case, you need to wrap the two properties you want to group by onto one. The simplest way to do this is to use a tuple...

```cs
var resultTable = dbContext.CashVacs.GroupBy(g => new {g.sex, g.Age});
```

P.S. All credit to @MikeMozhaev who answered first, I'm trying to add some explanation so the OP can (hopefully) understand why that comment answers the question. If @MikeMozhaev wants to post this as an answer, I would be happy for the OP to accept that rather than mine.